# Binding a List<string> to a ComboBox for display in a view (MVVM)

Tags: c#

I am attempting to bind a list to a combobox. I want to display this list of options within the Combobox itself. (Later to allow the user to select an item 'SelectedItem', I'll cross that bridge when I get there)

MyCode.cs

```
// List of values for 'Type' dropdown
    private static readonly List<string> MarkerTypeList = new List<string>(new string[]
    {
        "Analog",
        "Digital"
    });

// Binding for viewing list in window
    public List<string> TypeOptions
    {
        get { return MarkerTypeList; }
    }
```

MyCode.xaml

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="myCombobox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Height="23" SelectedItem="" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeOptions}" />
```

Comment: Good! I mean, i guess i am supposed to ask here what your problem is. But then again, i am not really sure whether you actually have a problem or whether you just want to report your success here ;-P (Please see [ask], preferably with a [mcve])

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Just remember that you need to set your `DataContext` to your `MyCode` instance, otherwise it will not find your `ItemSource`. I would not advise just binding directly to a static list like you have done above. I have a link below that outlines why that is the case (In FEY's CONTROL's answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution boiled down to changing this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TypeOptions}"
```

to this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Marker.TypeOptions}"
```

Thanks for the input, sorry you didnt have a whole lot to go on.

Answer (score -1):

If you bind you should have your INotifyPropertyChanged interface added to your class which is the actual ViewModel for your ComboBox. 
So - 1. Add the Interface to the class. 2. Create RaisePropertyChanged function. 3. Call the function through the setter of the property. This will push the updated value of the property through the binding and you will see the combobox populated.

Comment: You are aware that the property is a get-only property that does not change (because it is backed by a readonly backing field). How will your suggestion with regard to the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation help in this particular case?

Comment: You cannot apply MVVM and binding without pushing the values through the interface, no way around. You can create a private setter and then populate the set through the class constructor.

Comment: Even for a readonly dataset, it is highly advised to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See the `Binding leak` below.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/

Comment: @Dandre, yes, but this is not addressing the issue that the suggested answer does not solve OP's likely problem, unless OP intended to ask about how to avoid possibly memory leaks.

Comment: @FEY'SCONTROL, you might rethink your reasoning. No values are pushed through the interface, nor is the value of the property in the question ever changing. Nor does the property in the question has a setter (private or not). You are trying here in your comment to change the question to make it fit your answer. That is completely backwards and dodging my question. I am asking you how to ride a chicken, and you tell me if i were to have a horse...

Comment: @FEY'SCONTROL, let's assume for a moment that the problem would hypothetically(!!!) just be the missing INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. If this were to fix the problem (hypothetically), this would require the binding mechanism to find the binding source with the property to be able to get the value from the property. Now, if this is the requirement to make it work, it will then also work without the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation -- the binding mechanism will get the property value without any problem (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) The only issue with not having INotifyPropertyChanged implemented would then be that the binding mechanism would not be notified about changes of the property value (weird how this sounds so similar to the interface name INotifyPropertyChanged). But this is in the given scenario here actually a non-issue, since the value of the property does NOT change. Which means, if the binding in its current form does not work, then the reason is elsewhere and not the missing INotifyPropertyChanged implementation...

Comment: @elgonzo, "likely problem". I suppose you know what the problem is, I don't see a question and everyone is shooting in the dark. But you will find that the answer I gave alludes to the idea that ALL properties should use some form of notification-based elements which WPF is built for. Add a `ObservableCollection` and the problem is most likely solved. Even for a Read-only dataset (which is why I submitted that link).

Comment: @Dandré, you seem to be confused (well, your comment confuses me). The answer here tries to suggest that the problem is caused by/related to not using/raising property change notifications for this property. That is what the whole discussion here is about. I fail to understand why you are trying to yank the discussion to something else entirely. I did not speculate about what the particular nature of the problem/question might be, and i am not going to start with it now (see my last 2 comments to Fey'sControl that don't require speculating about an unknown problem)

Comment: I have to confess, this whole thread has been quite confusing. I had to re-read it 3 or more times just to understand what is going on. To address your concern @elgonzo, I have posted an answer to the question above and tested this all myself.

Comment: @Dandré, Also: "_But you will find that the answer I gave alludes to the idea that ALL properties should use some form of notification-based elements which WPF is built_" No. You misread the article you linked to. The problem alludes to the class implementing (or not implementing) the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  Whether and how a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged raises property change notifictions for all/none/particular properties has no bearing on the memory leak issue with the PropertyDescriptor.

Comment: @elgonzo I know that the problem doesn't pertain to a memory leak, but the best practice to avoid memory leaks would have to be factored in to the answer.

Comment: @Dandré, (Note that the code example given in the article is NOT a get-only read-only property, unlike the property here in the question. It is natural for the example to demonstrate that the property setter of the example property should raise property change notifications, irregardless of the memory leak issue)

Comment: @Dandré, i agree fully 100% with your last comment. Although, as we also both agree, writing a meaningful answer (i distinguish here between a StackOverflow answer and comments) would require atleast to have some idea about the concrete circumstances of OP's problem ;-)